# Prove the associative law for the addition of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The problem asks us to prove the commutative and associative laws for the addition of real numbers. The commutative proof seems straightforward. I am wondering how to approach the proof of the associative law however. I assume we have 3 Cauchy sequences representing real numbers:

$a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$

Would it be as simple as saying that sequence $x$ produced by the sum of these three sequences after some $j, k>m$ (probably using the max of $m_1, m_2$, and $m_3$ associated with $a, b$, and $c$ respectively), has the property |$x_j$ - $x_k$|  $\leq$ $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: If you may use that addition in $\mathbb Q$ is associative, this should be quite easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know that addition is well defined by taking termwise sums of representative Cauchy sequences, then we may prove this as follows. Let $[a_i]$, $[b_i]$, $[c_i]$ be Cauchy sequences representing $a,b,c$. Then
$$(a+b)+c=[a_i+b_i]+[c_i]=[a_i+b_i+c_i]=[a_i]+[b_i+c_i]=a+(b+c)$$